# Logging Optimization in a Production environment

Tags: .net, wcf, optimization, logging, production

I am optimizing some features in our application and I would like to measure success / find improvements by logging real use-case frequency in a Production environment. Given that I am optimizing, I do not want to spend time writing to file.

My thought was...could I decide on a splitting point in the execution path and spawn a new thread to examine an object and log some measurements to disk? Would my query thread be penalized at all? Are there any implications I have to consider?

The application is .NET WCF on a Windows box if it matters and this will only be needed short-term. Also, I need to do this on the application side as I need to log measurements that only the application can make.

Thanks for your thoughts!

Comment: If i remember correctly standard .Net logging and mostly all logging libraries, buffer data and write in chunks, so it's not that bad as you are thinking.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try an APM tool like New Relic?